# Socket programming vs. WebSocket for real-time multiplayer game in Android

Tags: sockets, tcp, websocket

I'm working on real-time multiplayer game in Android (java) and I narrowed down  the my choices for **bidirectional connection** to **WebSocket** and **Socket programming**

My requirements are:

- Fast Reaction Time
- High-Frequency send and receive with Small Payloads
- Stable connection
- Secure Connection
- Image and audio transfer
- In app chats

Base on these requirements, I would like to know which is more suitable.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add comment when vote down the question

Comment: Do you know what a webSocket is and what its features are that a plain socket does not have?  If not, then you need to educate yourself first and then ask a more informed question that references the specific feature differences that you need help understanding relative to your requirements.  If you do, then you need to reword your question to ask a specific question related to some of those feature differences.  We can't possibly tell you which to use.  It depends entirely upon your requirements which you have said nothing about.  As your question stands now it is too broad for stack overflow

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, I added my app requirements and asked more specific question

Answer (score 2):

A WebSocket is a regular TCP socket connection that:

- Mainly, it is supported in web browsers, so they can be used from Javascript.
- Starts as a HTTP connection, allowing it to easily cross proxies and firewalls, and make use of HTTP mechanisms like cookies and the `Origin` HTTP header among others. So for example, a Websocket connection will send the cookies that the browser has for that domain.
- Uses its own data framing protocol.
- Uses its own PING/PONG schema.

If you do not need any of those, you may be alright with just a socket.

Comment: Thanks @vtortola for clarification, But what do you recommend for real-time online multiplayer game in android(like QuizUp)?

Comment: I would recommend to architect your application in a way that the transport can be easily switchable. So you can start with websockets, because it gives you some features for free, and in the future you can switch to sockets if you need more fine grained control.